# How can I make the bot join on the channel?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Somebody can check this code and tell me what's wrong with this?

```py
@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
  if (ctx.author.voice):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
  else:
    await ctx.send("NO")
```

**Error:**

[image: 1]

Comment: what's the error you are getting? the behaviour?

Comment: I added error photo link @Mahrkeenerh

Comment: did you install `PyNaCl`?

Comment: ok thanks its works

Comment: it should be `ctx.author.voice.channel`

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stack overflow.  Might you please [edit] your question to include your error as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's required here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. See also [Correct way to format errors messages (or stacktraces)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141336).

Comment: Also, is this question resolved by installing `PyNaCl` as suggested in comments?